# Connect Django with react.js

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, bootstrap-4

I am working on Django project. So I built UI with `Html` and `Bootstrap` .Now I want work with reactjs so i need to know how can I implement similar or existing UI in react and how I can send httprequest and response from view to template.

```
function App() {
     return (
       <div className="App">
       <header className="App-header">
         <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="l ogo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
        <h1>wow sucess</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React is now the frontend server, and django is the backend. You need to send API requests to the django server using the `fetch` function or using [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the API from Django framework API then you need to use a state management Redux... With Redux, the state of your application is kept in a store, and each component can access any state that it needs from this store much easier...you can use axios to fetch your API URL from the Django framework.

Check this link out to understand more:[Axios](https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware)

Here’s an example of how fetching API with Axios looks like:

```
export const getItems = () => async (dispatch) => {


    try{
        const res = await axios.get(`YOUR API URL`)
        dispatch({
            type: GET_ITEMS,
            payload: res.data
        })
        
    }


    catch(e){
        dispatch({
            type: ITEMS_ERROR,
            payload: console.log(e),
        })
       
    }

}
```